# How to Assign String to java.security.key

Tags: java, android

Here I am retrieving The Publickey and Privatekey from Firebase,and setting it to  String,but I couldn't set it to java.security.key.
so,how can I set string to key?( How can I Assign string to key).This is what I tried:

```
Key Priy;
Key Puby;
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot child:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                            for (DataSnapshot single:child.getChildren()) {
                                Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) single.getValue();

                                Puby = (Key) map.get("Public");
                                Priy = (Key) map.get("Private");


                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

But it shows the error:
java.String cannot be cast to java.security.key
Please,Help me to solve it.